# Pandas Merge DataFrame Columns With Same Name But Different Rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, multiple-columns

I would like to merge two dataframes. Both have the same column names, but different numbers of rows.

The values from the smaller dataframe should then replace the values from the other dataframe

So far I tried using pd.merge

```py
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='NodeID)
```

But I do not know how to tell the merge command to use the values from the right dataframe for the columnes 'X' and 'Y'.

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'NodeID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'X': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'Y': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'NodeID': [2, 4], 'X': [1, 1], 'Y': [1, 1]})
```

The result should then look like this:

```py
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data={'NodeID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'X': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0], 'Y':[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]})
```

Comment: `df2.set_index('NodeID').combine_first(df1.set_index('NodeID')).reset_index()`

Answer (score 2):

This is can be done with `concat` and `drop_duplicates`

```
pd.concat([df2,df1]).drop_duplicates('NodeID').sort_values('NodeID')
Out[763]: 
   NodeID  X  Y
0       1  0  0
0       2  1  1
2       3  0  0
1       4  1  1
4       5  0  0
```